# ¿ Crear protocolo desde XCode para Objective-C sin tocar codigo?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Me gustaría saber si es posible declarar/crear un protocolo de un método en Objective-C mediante el uso de XCode ( Es decir sin escribir código )

Answer (score 1):

Hasta hace un par de años no había un wizard para agregar protocolos, según yo debes crearlo, empero, puedes compartir la estructura que quieres realizar